# Take Distinct values to populate Drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

```
   { "Result": { "tags": [ { "name": "ABC", "email": "abc1@example.com", "sms": 123 }, { 
"name": "ABC", "email": "abc2@example.com", "sms": 456 }, { "name": "ABC", "email": 
"abc3@example.com", "sms": 789 }, { "name": "XYZ", "email": "xyz1@example.com", "sms": 976 
}, { "name": "ABC", "email": "xyz2@example.com", "sms": 543 } ] } }
```

I have a JSON data like this. I want to Parse this JSON in PHP or Javascript to populate them in three drop downs.

**Name | Email | SMS**

But I need to Populate the distinct names in the dropdowns and populate email and sms based on selecting the name.

So far I just created the dropdowns.

*Fiddle Link* : http://jsfiddle.net/CAB2z/

Example:

Name should have : ABC | XYZ only once (Distinct : Should not repeat the same value).
When we select ABC, the three emails and phone numbers for "ABC" from the JSON should be populated in the second and third dropdown.

Comment: You can use `array_unique` in PHP. http://ca1.php.net/array_unique

Comment: After selecting the first dropdown to make the other two dropdowns appear (email and sms) are the two dropdowns that appear (email and sms) dependent on each other?

Comment: @DennisMartinez No, They are not dependent on each other. They both together depend on Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    var json = {
        "Result": {
            "tags": [{"name": "ABC","email": "abc1@example.com","sms": 123},
            {"name": "ABC","email": "abc2@example.com","sms": 456},
            {"name": "ABC","email":"abc3@example.com","sms": 789},
            {"name": "XYZ","email": "xyz1@example.com","sms": 976},
            {"name": "XYZ","email": "xyz2@example.com","sms": 543}]
         }
    };

    var name = [],obj = {};
    $(json.Result.tags).each(function (k, v) {
        name[k] = (v.name);
        obj[k] = {name: v.name,email: v.email,sms: v.sms};
    });
    $($.unique(name)).each(function (i, v) {
        $('#name').append('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>');
    });
    $('#name').on('change', function () {
       var $that = $(this);
       $('#email').html('');$('#sms').html('');
       $.each(obj,function (i, v) {
          if( $that.val() == v.name) {
             $('#email').append('<option value="'+v.email+'">'+v.email+'</option>');
             $('#sms').append('<option value="'+v.sms+'">'+v.sms+'</option>');
          }
       });
    }).change();
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/uC6BS/1/)**

Comment: How can we sort them ascending. They get sorted in descending order

Comment: Try to use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) See demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/uC6BS/2/

Answer (score 1):

> It will returns  all results you want. Just append the vaues in
>   dropdown its your part.

```
var resultArray = r.Result.tags;

var unique = {};
var distinctName = [];
var email = [];
var sms = [];

for( var i in resultArray ){
 if( typeof(unique[resultArray[i].name]) == "undefined"){
  distinctName.push(resultArray[i].name);  // push the unique names into the array

 }
 unique[resultArray[i].name] = 0;
     email.push(resultArray[i].email);  // push the email into the array
     sms.push(resultArray[i].sms)       // push the sms into the array
}

console.log(distinctName);
console.log(email);
console.log(sms);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, with jQuery, you can do:

```
var names, emails, smses;

(function() {
  data = JSON.parse(data); // Get the data formatted.
  var result = {
    name:  {},
    email: {},
    sms:   {}
  };
  $.each(data.Result.tags, function(index, value) {
    result.name [value.name]  = true; // True won't be used, it can be any value.
    result.email[value.email] = true;
    result.sms  [value.sms]   = true
  });
  names  = Object.keys(result.name);
  emails = Object.keys(result.email);
  smses  = Object.keys(result.sms);
} ()); // Temporary variables (like result) are destroyed.
// names, emails and smses contain your data.
```